# Access IndoorAtlas data from app

Tags: android, cordova, maps, indoor-positioning-system

For a schoolproject I am using IndoorAtlas SDK to build an app that navigates the user. I do not want the user to display the map.

In my app I want to access the data I created when mapping up my location using mapCreator2. I want to be able to match the data and the users current position, so that I for example, in my code can trigger an event when the user reaches a certain position. For example;
When user gets to the staircase, show picture.

How can I do this? (I think the documentation is hard to understand, and I can not get all modules to work using their tutorials..) 
But my question is; 
Which modules should I use? 
How can I access the data that I recorded with the map-creator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The IndoorAtlas API returns you the WGS-coordinate of the user. There is no API to fetch the mapping data, but you can build the needed logic for example with geo-fencing (=when I'm at this area, trigger this action).

Comment: That sounds perfect!! How would I do this?